# Preventing destroy of resources when refactoring Terraform to use indices

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

When I was just starting to use Terraform, I more or less naively declared resources individually, like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "image1_log" {
  name              = "${var.image1}-log-group"
  tags              = module.tagging.tags
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "image2_log" {
  name              = "${var.image2}-log-group"
  tags              = module.tagging.tags
}

 resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "image1_stream" {
   name           = "${var.image1}-log-stream"
   log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.image1_log.name
 }

 resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "image2_stream" {
   name           = "${var.image2}-log-stream"
   log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.image2_log.name
 }
```

Then, 10-20 different log groups later, I realized this wasn't going to work well as infrastructure grew. I decided to define a variable list:

```
variable "image_names" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "image1",
    "image2"
  ]
}
```

Then I replaced the resources using indices:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "service-log-groups" {
  name              = "${element(var.image_names, count.index)}-log-group"
  count             = length(var.image_names)
  tags              = module.tagging.tags
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "service-log-streams" {
  name              = "${element(var.image_names, count.index)}-log-stream"
  log_group_name    = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.service-log-groups[count.index].name
  count             = length(var.image_names)
}
```

The problem here is that when I run `terraform apply`, I get `4 resources to add, 4 resources to destroy`. I tested this with an old log group, and saw that all my logs were wiped (obviously, since the log was destroyed).

The **names and other attributes of the log groups/streams are identical**- I'm simply refactoring the infrastructure code to be more maintainable. How can I maintain my existing log groups without deleting them yet still refactor my code to use lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to move the existing resources within the Terraform state.

Try running `terraform show` to get the strings under which the resources are stored, this will be something like `[module.xyz.]aws_cloudwatch_log_group.image1_log` ...

You can move it with `terraform state mv [module.xyz.]aws_cloudwatch_log_group.image1_log '[module.xyz.]aws_cloudwatch_log_group.service-log-groups[0]'`.
You can choose which index to assign to each resource by changing `[0]` accordingly.

Delete the old resource definition for each moved resource, as Terraform would otherwise try to create a new group/stream.

Try it with the first import and check with `terraform plan` if the resource was moved correctly...

Also check if you need to choose some index for the `image_names` list jsut to be sure, but I think that won't be necessary.